# When using System.IO.Stream, how can I avoid OutOfMemoryException?

Tags: c#, stream, out-of-memory, bitmapsource

I am making a scanning component, but when I set a high resolution for the document (600 dpi), I tend to get **System.OutOfMemoryException** after just 1 or 2 scans.

My code is as follows

```
public ScannedImage SaveScannedImage(DataTransferredEventArgs e)
{
    if (e == null) throw new IOException();

    BitmapSource fullResImage;
    using (var fullResImageStream = e.GetNativeImageStream())
    {
        fullResImage = fullResImageStream.ConvertToWpfBitmap(e.ImageInfo.ImageWidth, e.ImageInfo.ImageLength);
    }

    BitmapSource lowResImage;
    using (var lowResImageStream = e.GetNativeImageStream())
    {
        lowResImage = lowResImageStream.ConvertToWpfBitmap(800, 0);
    }

    return new ScannedImage(lowResImage, fullResImage);
}
```

It is usually happening at the

```
using (var lowResImageStream = e.GetNativeImageStream())
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: As you are dealing with Stream, use should use `GC.Collect()` method to collect the unmanaged resource when it is not required.

Comment: Are you sure `ImageLength` is what you want, and not e.g. `ImageHeight`? And what is `DataTransferredEventArgs`, `ConvertToWpfBitmap` etc.?

Comment: @ManpritSinghSahota `GC.Collect()` *should* be called when it sees its out of memory, when it's still out of memory after that it will throw. But it's true that `GC.Collect()` will sometimes fix problems even though it shouldnt

Comment: I am using the Twain API. DataTransferredEventArgs contains event data from the scanner, and ConvertToWpfBitmap is a built-in BitmapSource method that converts the incoming System.IO.Stream to a displayable WPF image.

Answer (score 0):

What you see may be caused by large object heap (LOH) fragmentation.

That is hard to avoid, but you can compact the LOH explicitely.

```
GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = 
    GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce;

GC.Collect();
```

Also, make sure you run as a 64 bit process. Turn of the "Prefer 32 bit" option if it is on.

For more information, you might want to read

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.gcsettings.largeobjectheapcompactionmode.aspx
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory/

Comment: @AkselVincentBerg So, did you have a look?